# Not able to install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap0.8-dev

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I'm trying to install reaver but I can't install the dependencies. I've tried almost everything. I have tried to fix the broken packages with: `sudo apt-get autoclean &&  sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove`. But it didn't work. I'm using the custom Kali 2020 from Zsecurity.

This is what the error looks like:

```
root@kali:~/reaver-wps-fork-t6x/src# sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap0.8-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap0.8-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libc-dev
 tracker-miner-fs : Breaks: rygel (< 0.40.1-3~) but 0.38.2-4 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Please help me fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not appear to have run `apt update` which may or may not help.

Comment: Check your sources for non free packages https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/